# Changed Partition Number and now Grub fails to start

Tags: partition, grub, move-partition

I deleted a partition on my hard disk, causing the partition numbers of the 2 Linux installations to decrement. When attempting to boot the computer I get the message `error: no such partition` and I am dropped to the `grub rescue>` prompt. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the existing answers. Since I used the partition number, I used the guide from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting:

1. `set prefix=(hdX,Y)/boot/grub` where X is hard drive number starting with 0 and Y is known partition number
2. `set root=(hdX,Y)` with the same numbers
3. `insmod normal`
4. `normal`

From here, I pressed e to edit the boot parameters and changed the partition number in 5 places on 3 lines.

It booted normally and I then ran `update-grub`.

I found out that despite the rather cryptic error given by parted, you should not restart and should instead run update-grub.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running `update-grub` either at the rescue prompt or from a Live USB/CD. Don´t know if it will work but it is a good starting point. Best thing to do is always backup before modifying partitions.

Good way to backup is boot on a Live USB and run

```
dd if=/[location of computer harddrive (example /sda)] of=[location of external harddrive (example /sdb)]
```

Hopefully `update-grub` helps :)

Answer (score 0):

@River-rush is right of course, fixing the numbering in your grub config to reflect the current situation will allow you to boot.  As soon as you assign that disk space to a new partition though you'll have to renumber again.  Presumably you want to do something with it?

You could boot from a rescue disk and create a partition in the space where the old one was, which would put your numbering back how it was before, and allow you to boot with the existing grub config.

If you are extending an existing partition to fill the space, then go with the approach of fixing your grub config.